# Eurotruck sim 2 Lights based on key position (not toggle)

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I'm in the process of making my own custom controller for Eurotruck Simulator 2. Most keys are simple enough to toggle through (like engine start stop with a push button) But for lights I'd like to create a "state" switch, just as you'd get in any car/truck

For this to work I need the game to turn lights on & off based on the presence of an input (like detecting if k is pressed, similar to flashing your headlights)
So basically only turn lights on based on a continuous input or key/slider position.

I've been searching all morning but can't find anything on this. I've been to the Custom control section on the Wiki, but it only references things like throttle and the H-shifter. Any ideas on how I can go about approaching this? Is there any mods?

Comment: I think this is an electronics problem, not a game problem. Such controllers do exist and you could modify one of them, but it's going to be tricky and cost a few bucks.